# Handle removal of Kotlin data class's field on app's update without loosing its value

Tags: json, kotlin, data-class

I want to modify existing data class, by moving one of its parameters into second data class and I wonder what's the best way to handle it, without loosing the data already stored using the old data class. Data is stored using Json serializer and app has mechanisms for updating data stored in databases on app's update.

Here's example:

Currently used data class

```
@Serializable
@Parcelize
data class AlarmInfo (
    val volume: Int
    (...)//other fields
) : Parcelable
```

Data classes to be used after app's update

```
@Serializable
@Parcelize
data class AlarmInfo (
    val ringtoneInfo: RingtoneInfo
    (...)//other fields
) : Parcelable

@Serializable
@Parcelize
data class RingtoneInfo (
    val volume: Int
    (...)//other fields
) : Parcelable
```

Is there a way to retrieve `AlarmInfo.volume` stored value, when `AlarmInfo` class after update doesn't have this field anymore?

I know I can do it ugly way, by keeping the `AlarmInfo.volume` in the new class and copy its value to the `RingtoneInfo.volume` on app's update, but it doesn't feel right to keep this field forever after this one update.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't keep the field forever. Keep it during a migratory period where you start to gradually phase it out. At first, silently have both and perform the transformation inside your inner layers, transparent to the rest of the app that still may use volume. Eventually start making sure "volume" is not used anywhere. Then a few updates later you can remove it. Why would you be worried of keeping it forever? Add tickets in your tracker to do this work when the time is right.

Comment: I thought about it as well, but still hoped there might be some more elegant solution, that I am not aware of. 
When going with this approach, is there maybe some annotation I could see to have the `volume` field deserialized, but named differently in the class? Something like:
`@CleverAnnotation(name="volume") val dontUse: Int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there maybe some annotation I could see to have the volume field deserialized, but named differently in the class? Something like:
> `@CleverAnnotation(name="volume") val dontUse: Int?`

I am not aware of any annotation that would do that for you, except GSON's (and other parsers' equivalent) `@SerializedName`

E.g.:

```
@SerializedName("name")
var userName: String
```

Keep in mind if you use Proguard, you need to tell it to *keep* the model class, or it may be obfuscated into something else. Of course, that's only a GSON annotation for the purpose of serialization and deserialization.

Other than that, you could hide the field behind a function or `get()` like

```
@Deprecated(
    message = "This field is deprecated and will be removed in future versions",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("newField"),
    level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING
)
var oldField: String? = null
var newField get() = oldField
```

(all pseudo code, you get the idea).
Or similar ideas...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will go with this approach, although without the `get()` part, as  newField is placed in a data class "inside" the old data class (as in example), so it has no visilibility of the oldField.
I found out in the Json the CleverAnnotation is `@SerialName("name")` :)

Comment: Ahh, didn't know the _clever one_ :) Good luck!